# How to avoid spaceleak in multiple list traversals?

Tags: haskell

is GHC intelligent enough to run multiple operations on lists in 'semi-parallel'?

Consider this (simplified) code:

```
findElements bigList = do
  let special = head . filter isSpecial $ bigList
  let others  = filter isSpecialOrNormal $ bigList

  return (special, others)
```

(*Monad due to original code*)

I guess GHC will run the first list operation and will keep all elements in memory so that the second operation is able to work on them.

My problem is that i am running into a spaceleak when dealing with larger files. But i believe it should be able to run in constant space. Is there a way to achieve this?

### Update 1

Having written it down like this the solution to this problem of course is to change the order of the two lines.

But my question remains: is the GHC intelligent enough to figure out this semi-parallel processing when it not done in a monad?

Comment: In this particular case, you could change `special = head . filter isSpecial $ others`, no?

Comment: right ... i just got that too :) -- the monad is there cause my code runs in a monad. And i guess that's part of the problem.

Comment: The answer is no.  It's a not an easy thing to do (and preserve semantics).

Comment: Would GHC optimize this if there is no monad?

Comment: @Florian It has nothing to do with the monad.  Imagine this `let xs = filter p as; ys = filter q as`.  If you want to optimize this to do a single traversal of `as` you need to actually compute `p` and `q` for the elements.  You don't know if this is safe since they might not terminate for all inputs.

Comment: @augustss I am not sure that this is a problem. The programmer is responsible to handle infinite datastructures. Isn't this what fusion is (at least partly) about?

Comment: @Florian It's not infinite data structures that is a problem.  Consider `let xs = filter (const True) as; ys = filter (const undefined) as in (xs, ys)`, and then you just use `xs`.  If you try to fuse the computation of `xs` and `ys` you'll get an error, if you don't fuse everything will be fine.

Comment: @augustss If you fuse it like in my answer it works fine. So I don't see the problem of automatic fusing either.

Comment: In the case when the result is (a, [a]) and you fuse and then only use the first component you have two choices: either perform the computation for the second list early and break semantics OR build a list of thunks.  The latter is, I conjecture, both slower and more memory consuming than two traversals.

Comment: The order of declarations is immaterial. Also, you may be interested in [beautiful folding](http://squing.blogspot.com/2008/11/beautiful-folding.html).

Comment: I just did some tests and i found that there is almost no difference between running one iteration or several. This leads me to the conclusion that either it doesn't matter at all (altough i am working on <500MB files) or that GHC actually does optimize this away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think GHC is smart enough to merge these two traversals, or, as is usually the case, GHC could be smart enough, but there are cases where you don't want this behavior, so GHC doesn't do it.

Here's how I would do it, using monoids and `foldMap`.

```
import Data.Monoid
import Data.Foldable
```

First, here's how to write `special` with `foldMap`, using the `First` monoid.

```
specialF :: a -> First a
specialF a = First $ if isSpecial a then Just a else Nothing

special :: [a] -> a
special as = let (First (Just s)) = foldMap specialF as in s
```

And similar for specialOrNormal, using the list monoid.

```
specialOrNormalF :: a -> [a]
specialOrNormalF a = if isSpecialOrNormal a then [a] else []

specialOrNormal :: [a] -> [a]
specialOrNormal = foldMap specialOrNormalF
```

One neat thing about monoids is that a tuple of monoids is also a monoid, which makes merging these folds easy:

```
findElements :: [a] -> (a, [a])
findElements bigList =
  let (First (Just s), son) = 
    foldMap (\a -> (specialF a, specialOrNormalF a)) bigList
  in (s, son)
```

And if you like point-free code, you can write the whole thing like this:

```
findElements :: [a] -> (a, [a])
findElements = 
  first (fromJust . getFirst) . 
  foldMap 
    (   First . mfilter isSpecial . return 
    &&& mfilter isSpecialOrNormal . return
    )
```

Comment: for what it is worth, I have a package, multipass, that I'm edging towards release that deals with automatically fusing multiple monoidal passes over a data structure. http://github.com/ekmett/multipass

Comment: @EdwardKmett Are you going to release a travel guide with that package? ;-)

Comment: Eventually, in the meantime loading `examples/Pass.hs` and running `sequence [mean, absdev median, median, median \`by\` HD, trimean, count, total, stddev, iqr] @! [1..10]` will yield
`[5.5,2.5,5.5,5.49999999972799,5.5,10.0,55.0,2.8722813232690143,5.0]` computing everything in a couple of passes over the data and maximizing sharing between calculations.